# Add up the maximum value in each row of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following code

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
  import sys
  import re
  import string
  indexfile="ABC.txt"
  for line in open(indexfile,'rU').xreadlines():
    t = string.split(line,'\t')
    id = t[0];
    gene=t[1];
    pwmfile=id+'.txt'
    matrix_file = open(pwmfile, "rU")
    matrix = matrix_file.readlines()
    vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
    newpwmfile=id+'_formated.txt'
    ea=open(newpwmfile,'w')
    ea.seek(0)
    ea.write(">"+"ASTTCCTCTT "+gene)
    ea.writelines([line.lstrip('\t') for line in vals])
    ea.close()
```

and following is the matrix that I get:

```
   >ABC/EFG
    0   0   1   0
    0.53333333333333    0   0.13333333333333    0.33333333333333
    0.2 0   0   0.8
    0.33333333333333    0   0   0.66666666666667
    0   1   0   0
    0   0.86666666666667    0.13333333333333    0
    0.33333333333333    0.066666666666667   0   0.6
    0   0   1   0
```

I want to find out the maximum value from each row and divide it by 0.25 and sum it up for each row.Also I want to get a string that assigns the letter for each position in the string for instance if the max value is in the third column for that row then G, for first column in second row, then G etc and concatenate them such that I get a string like GAUUCCCG at the same time as finding the max score in each row.

Comment: Can you read in your file using a standard library?

Comment: @canyon289: I am sorry I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

#make some fake data
m = np.random.random((8,4))

#get the sum you described
print 0.25*np.max(m, axis=1).sum()

#next, get the index the max value, for each row
xs = np.argmax(m, axis=1)
#use these as indexes into a string, e.g.
s = "GAUC"
print "".join(s[x] for x in xs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however when I plug it into my original code for the variable 'vals' I get the error: ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds

Comment: You need to convert your data to a 2d array.  (Also, note that `xreadlines` is no longer necessary to iterate through the lines of a file; it's the default behavior.)  Try changing `vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]` to `vals = np.array([map(float,line.split()[1:]) for line in matrix[1:]])`.